# Angular4 how to find specific value from an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Components and service
Component :

```
servers:{Name : string , Id:number }[]=[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.Id =   this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
}
```

Service :

```
server_detail=[{Name : 'production',Id    : 1},
               {Name :'Attendance', Id    : 2}];
```

I am getting Id from the route and want to fetch server name corresponding to that server Id.

Comment: Please format your code as a code block

Comment: You want to find name that is correspoding to id given from server?

Comment: @Oisin formatted for him :D

Comment: Yes sir.. i want name of server corresponding to id

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the specific value using the `find()` method:

```
// by Id
let server = this.servers.find(x => x.Id === 1);
// or by Name
let server = this.servers.find(x => x.Name === 'production');
```

---

**UPDATE** according to your comment:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.servers = this.alldata.server_detail;
    this.server_Id=  this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    let server = this.servers.find(x => x.Id === this.server_Id);
    if(server !== undefined) {
        // You can access Id or Name of the found server object.
        concole.log(server.Name);
    }
}
```

If an object is not found, then the `find()` method will return `undefined`.

Comment: ngOnInit() {

this.servers=this.alldata.server_detail; 
this.server_Id= this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
let server = this.servers.find(x => x.Id === this.server_Id);
console.log(this.server_Id);}
console.log(server);}              server is  "undefined" , but server_id having value and servers also have data then why server is undefined @Faisal

Comment: @user8331237 are you sure you get all servers data correctly? try to console.log(this.alldata.server_detail) and see if it contains data.

Comment: yess.. I checked it out. console.log(this.alldata.server_detail) it contains the data

Comment: Share your code on some plunker or in the question.

Comment: problem has been solved ... Can you tell me difference between the working of find and filter method

Comment: `find` returns one object where as `filter` returns a list of matching objects. Please upvote and accept for others to benefit as well :)